# How do you use systemd to ensure remote database is available

Tags: systemd, sysvinit

In SysV I can use a condition to ensure an application does not try to start before the database is up and running. I give the init script some time to wait, then finally give up after a period of time if the database service is still unavailable.

```
start() {
local exec=/path/to/exec
local tries=1
[ -x $exec ] || exit 5
echo -n $"Starting $prog: "


#check communication to database
if ! [ 2>/dev/null : < /dev/tcp/$dbHost/$dbPort ]
    then
        while ! [ 2>/dev/null : < /dev/tcp/$dbHost/$dbPort ] && [ ! $tries -ge 5 ]
            do
                >&2 echo -e "Could not connect to the database on $dbHost\nWaiting 10 seconds to check database status, attempt $tries"
                sleep 10
                ((tries++))
        done
        sleep 10
        if ! (: < /dev/tcp/$dbHost/$dbPort ) 2>/dev/null
            then
                >&2 echo -e "Could not connect to the database on $dbHost aborting startup of $exec"
                exit 1
        fi
fi
```

I've been searching for a similar scenario in documentation and google, but have not found anything that is not referencing local services.

Comment: Hm...maybe one option would be to put that into a regular shell script and kick that off through `systemd`. Or use `Restart` and `RestartSec`, maybe `TimeoutStartSec` in `systemd` to restart the service on failure. A more sophisticated way could be the use of `ExecStartPre` to check for the connection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you looked at ExecStartPre in the [systemd service documentation?](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html)

I would suggest putting your database test in a script, have it use `exit 0` on success and `exit 1` on failure and then run it with `ExecStartPre`.  You would then start your application using `ExecStart`.

Comment: I thought about that, but then thought, why not just leave it all in this one SysV script.

Comment: Then why use systemd?

Comment: I feel that resistance is futile, but would like to write elegant systemd init scripts as I have done with SysV for a couple of decades. :)

Comment: there are no init scripts in systemd, there are only service units which can easily execute init scripts.  The writeup from @ErikF is a great example of a good one with the bonus that it is reusable for other services.

Answer (score 3):

@GracefulRestart's answer is the best if you only have one service depending on the availability of the database. However, if you have multiple services that have this requirement, make a oneshot service that all of the services can then have a `Requires=` dependency to:

**/etc/systemd/system/portopen@.service**

```
[Unit]
Description=Checks database availability on %I
After=network.target
Requires=network.target

[Service]
Type=oneshot
RemainAfterExit=true
ExecStart=/path/to/portopen.sh %I

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

**/path/to/portopen.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash
dbhost=${1:-localhost}
dbport=${2:-5678}
maxtries=${3:-5}
wait=${4:-10}
tries=1

# Check communication to database
while ! [ 2>/dev/null : < /dev/tcp/$dbhost/$dbport ]; do
   echo "Unable to connect to database on $dbhost TCP/$dbport (attempt $tries): retrying in $wait seconds" >&2
   (( tries++ ))
   if [[ $tries -le $maxtries ]]; then
      sleep $wait
   else
      echo "Unable to connect to database on $dbhost TCP/$dbport: aborting"
      exit 1
   fi
done
```

I made the script a bit more flexible in case you change or add database servers, or the port changes, or you want to change the number of retries on a per-service level. If you don't need that, just call the service `portopen.service` and remove the `%I` parts.

Let's say your database server is on `foobar` and your database application runs on `foobarapp.service`. Make the following changes to `foobarapp.service`:

```
# systemctl edit foobarapp.service
```

[in editor]

```
[Unit]
After=portopen@foobar.service
Requires=portopen@foobar.service
```

Then reload `systemd` and start and enable the check:

```
# systemctl daemon-reload
# systemctl enable portopen@foobar.service
```

You can then restart `foobarapp.service` whenever you want. It should only start if `portopen@foobar.service` returns successfully.

If it doesn't already exist, the database application service `foobarapp.service` would then look like this:

**/etc/systemd/system/foobarapp.service**

```
[Unit]
Description=Foobar database application
# Add any other dependencies here
After=portopen@foobar.service
Requires=portopen@foobar.service

[Service]
# If it is a daemon, use "forking" instead
Type=simple
ExecStart=/path/to/exec

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

Comment: In reading through the documentation I had come to the conclusion that this would require an external script. So there is no way to have a condition within the single systemd service that says "only continue if `2>/dev/null : < /dev/tcp/$dbHost/$dbPort` returns 0" and try x number of times, that you are aware of? I mean without it calling an external script to do so.

Comment: `systemd` has restart directives, but they only apply to services that aren't `oneshot` (like this one is); they're more designed to restart failed services that are long-running. An external script is going to be needed for what you are wanting to do.